# Where is GlimpseTimeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I am using the latest [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse) package of Glimpse. I see in the [official website](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Timeline-Tab) that they have a GlimpseTimeline that allow to add custom event in the timeline. I see the [Github](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/version-2/source/Glimpse.Core/GlimpseTimeline.cs) source that this static class exist. How come it is not inside Glimpse?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "not inside Glimpse"? Are you using these methods and your events are showing up in the timeline or are you asking about the internal methods, etc.

Comment: Not inside the Glimpse Dlls (core) or extension.

Answer (score 0):

The page on official website that you referensed says "The GlimpseTimeline API was introduced in v2+" now. And v2 haven't been released yet, which is sad.

You can download SSW.AnalyticsInterface.Glimpse nuget package which provides the same syntax and works well. But I think it's not opensource and that's quite confusing. If you fine with non-opensource code that may be your solution.